# Pinescript : Want to get Previous day high without using security function

Tags: pine-script

I want to get Previous day high value in chart without using security function.Because security functions are limited to use.

I tried with a code :

```
@version=4
study("PDH",overlay = true)
t = time("1440", session.regular) // 1440=60*24 is the number of minutes in a 
whole day. You may use "0930-1600" as second session parameter
is_first = na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t

bars = barssince(is_first) + 1
todayshigh = highest(high,bars)

pdh = highest(high[bars],13)  // 30 mins timeframe thus used 13 bars
plot(pdh)
plot(todayshigh,color.red)
```

In the above code, todayshigh is plotted correctly, but pdh is not. The problem is with high[bars], it is not giving an error like "can't use array in subscript" but the value calculated by it is incorrect.

Please help me with how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("High", overlay = true)

var float hi        = 0
var float hi_prev   = 0

if high > hi
    hi := high
    
if change(time("D"))
    hi_prev := hi
    hi := high

plot(hi_prev, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

**Edit 1** in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622608/pinescript-want-to-get-previous-day-high-without-using-security-function/67624597?noredirect=1#comment119652237_67624597) comment.
I saw that you tried to edit my answer earlier today.
However, I rejected the edit because I was convinced it was wrong.
If I'm not mistaken, you only changed `hi_prev := hi` to `hi_prev := hi[1]` in your edit at that time, and didn't include the `else` part.

I've just re-compared my solution to the solution that you posted in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67622608/pinescript-want-to-get-previous-day-high-without-using-security-function/67624597?noredirect=1#comment119652237_67624597), and it seems I made a mistake.

Your solution (below) is absolutely correct.

```
//@version=4
study("High", overlay = true)

var float hi        = 0
var float hi_prev   = 0

if high > hi
    hi := high
    
if change(time("D"))
    hi_prev := hi[1]
    hi := high
else
    hi_prev := hi_prev[1]

plot(hi_prev, style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Comment: Thanks Bjorn for your help. Did a small change in your code because I was not getting desired results.  
    if change(time("D"))
    hi_prev := hi[1]
    hi := high
    else hi_prev = hi_prev[1]

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer.